# Convergence of local minimum

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is compact. Define the following norm for two times continuously differentiable functions:
$$
\|f\|_{C^2} := \max_{|\alpha|_1 \leq 2} \sup_{x \in \Omega} \left| \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\prod_{j=1}^d x_j^{\alpha_j}} f(x) \right| .
$$

Assume that for a function $f \in C^2$ and a sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in C^2$ it holds

$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \|f - f_n\|_{C^2} = 0 ,
$$
i.e. $f_n$, its gradient and its hessian all converge to the respective derivative of $f$.

Moreover, assume that both $f$ and all $f_n$ are convex, i.e. have a unique global minimum at which it holds
$$
\nabla f(\hat{x}) = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad \nabla f(\hat{x}_n) = 0 \text{ for } n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

Intuitively, it should hold
$$
 \lim_{n \to \infty} \hat{x}_n = \hat{x} .
$$

How can this be proven? Are additional assumptions necessary? Or is it even sufficient to have convergence in the $C^1$ norm?
A problem with my proof approach is that the mean value theorem does not hold in multiple dimensions.

Thank you!

Comment: By compactness, the $\hat x_n$ sequence will have convergent subsequences, about whose limits you can probably deduce nice things.

Comment: Convex functions do not necessarily have a unique global minimum. You must assume strict convexity instead. In fact, even with strict convexity you can't guarantee the existence of minimums. Example: f(x)= x+1. With uniform convexity however, you can guarantee both the existence and uniqueness of minimum points. This is unless, of course, you assume this conditions. The point is that this is not a consequence of convexity only.